# php transferring value to another page

Tags: php

I have used this code:

```
$value = $_POST['searcheditem'];
header("Location : anotherpage.php?myValue=".$value);
```

And then inside anotherpage.php:

```
echo $_GET['myValue'];
// make sure to sanitize this data
```

But when I push any button in anotherpage.php and it refreshes the page the value of `$_GET['myValue']` is lost so I get the error index 'myValue' is undefined. What can I do?

Comment: If you refresh the page, you're sending a new request to it, without any GET or POST request variables. So, of course it will be flushed.

Comment: You should describe why you're using that code for, what's your background. So people can actually help you with solutions or workarounds.

Comment: If those other buttons are form submits, you need to have the form persist the value by adding it to the `action` attribute of the form. This can get painful to maintain - you might want to look into persisting the value in the user's session (i.e. via cookie) if that's appropriate for your use case